# How to send an snmp request to any computer on LAN?

Tags: snmp, lan, net-snmp

I want to build an application using snmp for searching my LAN and exploring the devices which have shared some resources. I need some assistance to start with it, I have trying to do the same using net-snmp, but still no success.

Comment: What programming language are you using? What operating system? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am working on ubuntu 10.10, programming language is C. till now I have tried Net-snmp command line applications to query some IP addresses on LAN, but always timeout.

Comment: What is your question that is related to programming?

Answer (score 0):

SNMP is on UDP, so you can simply do a broadcast.

It is quite normal that net-snmp times out in such cases, as no SNMP agent would like to respond to you or no SNMP agent is there in the same LAN.